# OCaml compiler build failure

Tags: ocaml

I checkout the latest OCaml source code and try to build on my OS X 10.10 machine
with gcc 4.9.2. I use the following command as suggested [here](https://github.com/ocamllabs/compiler-hacking/wiki/Getting-started).

```
$ ./configure && make world
```

Build gets no error but when I tried the compiler I just build by doing `$ ./ocamlc`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: unknown C primitive `caml_add_debug_info'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens when you use the old bytecode interpreter to run the new compiler. Make sure you're using the new bytecode interpreter (`ocamlrun`).

Comment: I think you want to use `ocamlrun`.

Comment: Oh sorry u are right. However, I checked the `./ocamlc` under my folder. It has the header `#!/usr/local/bin/ocamlrun `. Also, when I do '$ ocamlrun ./ocamlc', it still produces the same error

Comment: I guess I should use the `ocamlrun` under the `byterun` directory